# Java Error java.lang.NullPointerException 2

Tags: java

```
    public FileWindow(JMenuItem menuItem,final JTextArea text, JMenuItem save){

    //Open
    menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            openFile();

            if(fileToOpen == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                text.setText("");
                try{
                    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(Open.getSelectedFile().getPath()));
                    while(scan.hasNext()){
                        text.append(scan.nextLine() + "\n");
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    });

    //Save
    save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            saveFile();
            if(fileToSave == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                try{
                    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Save.getSelectedFile().getPath() + ".txt"));
                    out.write(text.getText());
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I'm getting an error on this line --> "menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener){" I tried initiating the variables but that didn't work. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: the problem isn't that I don't know what a Null Pointer Exception is, its that I can't seem to find it. My IDE says its on the line that I mentioned earlier.

Comment: `I don't know what a Null Pointer Exception is,` well a NullPointerException is probably the common Exception you will ever get so you need to learn how to debug the problem. It basically means you have allocated memory to the variable because you didn't invoke the "new" method for that variable. For example `JMenuItem mi = new JMenuItem("testing");`. This is easy to check you simply add a `System.out.println(menuItem);` statement in your method. Then if the output is "null" you check where you invoke the method to see why the variable is "null".

Answer (score 0):

you're most probably getting a NullPointerException because `menuitem` is null. make sure `menuitem` is initialized before you call this constructor.

Comment: Thanks but its still not working

Comment: menuItem is a method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`menuItem` is null when you run `menuItem.addActionListener()`

Make sure it isn't null but adding:

```
if (menuItem == null)
    System.out.println("menuItem is null!");
```

Comment: ok if i intialize it before the constuctor i get an error

Comment: `public FileWindow(JMenuItem menuItem, final JTextArea text, JMenuItem save) {`

`menuItem` is a parameter of the method.

Comment: yeah i know when I initialize it inside it does nothing tho

Comment: Don't initialize it inside initialize it when you call the method.

Comment: ok I got an error public FileWindow(JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(),final JTextArea text, JMenuItem save){